# SQL Server Stored Procedure And SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-injection, sql-insert

I use SQL Server 2012 and I write a stored procedure.

I want know if there is any possibility of SQL injection in my stored procedure?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Production.InsertProducts', 'P') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP PROCEDURE Production.InsertProducts 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE Production.InsertProducts 
  @productname AS NVARCHAR(40)  
  , @supplierid AS INT  
  , @categoryid AS INT  
  , @unitprice AS MONEY = 0 
  , @discontinued AS BIT = 0 
AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT Production.Products (productname, supplierid, categoryid, unitprice, discontinued) 
    VALUES (@productname, @supplierid, @categoryid, @unitprice, @discontinued); 

    RETURN; 
END; 
GO
```

Or

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Production.InsertProducts', 'P') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP PROCEDURE Production.InsertProducts 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE Production.InsertProducts 
  @productname AS NVARCHAR(40)  
  , @supplierid AS INT  
  , @categoryid AS INT  
  , @unitprice AS MONEY = 0 
  , @discontinued AS BIT = 0 
AS 
BEGIN 
  Declare @Command NVArchar(Max) = 'INSERT Production.Products (productname, supplierid, categoryid, unitprice, discontinued) 
    VALUES (''' + @productname + ''',' + @supplierid + ',' + @categoryid + ',' + @unitprice + ',' + @discontinued + ');' 
  Execute(@Command);
  RETURN; 
END; 
GO
```

Or

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Production.InsertProducts', 'P') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP PROCEDURE Production.InsertProducts 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE Production.InsertProducts 
  @productname AS NVARCHAR(40)  
  , @supplierid AS INT  
  , @categoryid AS INT  
  , @unitprice AS MONEY = 0 
  , @discontinued AS BIT = 0 
AS 
BEGIN 
  Declare @Command NVArchar(Max) = '
  INSERT Production.Products (productname, supplierid, categoryid, 
     unitprice, discontinued) 
    VALUES ( @productname , @supplierid,@categoryid,@unitprice,@discontinued);' 

Execute SP_ExecuteSql @Command,
    ' @productname NVARCHAR(40) , @supplierid INT , @categoryid INT  
        , @unitprice  MONEY , @discontinued  BIT ' ,
      @productname= @productname,@supplierid=@supplierid,
        @categoryid=@categoryid,@unitprice=@unitprice,@discontinued=@discontinued
  RETURN; 
END; 
GO
```

Which of those queries is best ?

Comment: why are you using RETURN;?

Comment: Return is not important when it used in last line of SP.

Comment: that's my question, then why are you using it, remove that.

Comment: This stored procedure has no vulnerability because it contains no dynamic SQL.  However, they may be an SQL injection vulnerability in the application that calls it if CommandType.StoredProcedure is not specified.

Comment: As @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP has confirmed there is no sql injection vulnerability in this procedure, but I would still make two changes here,  1)  Remove `RETURN` as its not required, 2) add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` just after Begin to suppers the message `(n) rows affected bla bla`, Also if you have an Identity column use OUTPUT parameters to get the new inserted value.

Comment: @Piyush : Ok. But It is not my answer. merci

Comment: @Ardalan: Yes, that is only comment, That's why I am not putting in Answer section. We are here to make your code/query more optimized and ready to help you in any manner. and also notice you what's wrong going on in your query

Comment: @Piyush : 1000 tons Tank you my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the stored procedures themselves.

The first has no opportunity for SQL injection, because there is no dynamic SQL.

The third has no opportunity for SQL injection, because the use of `sp_executesql` compiles the query with parameters and then inserts the values of parameters.  The compilation logically happens *before* the parameter substitution, so funky strings in the parameters cannot change the fact that only the single `insert` will run.

The second is vulnerable, because of `@productname`.  The other parameters are numbers and I don't think that inclusion of numbers in a string can cause a vulnerability.  (If I'm wrong, I'm sure someone will point out a reference on how that would work.)  There is a *risk* with such parameters, because someone might change them to character strings in the future.

In terms of safety and best practices, the first version is the safest.  You don't even have to think about whether there is a vulnerability.  The third is safe, but might not look safe.  The second should be avoided if you are at all concerned about SQL injection.

As for the use of `return`, I have no problem with it.  It is a clear statement of the intent of the programmer to stop execution of the stored procedure at that point.  And, in fact SQL Server's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) has an redundant example.  Stored procedures *do* return values, always an integer status code and I typically use these.